# Why can't dafny prove A[i-1] <= A[i] ensures A[i] <= A[j] for i <= j

Tags: dafny

```
ghost method lemma1(A:array<int>)
    requires A.Length>2
    requires forall i:: 0 <= i-1 < i < A.Length ==> A[i-1] <= A[i]
    ensures A[0] <= A[1] <= A[2]
{
}
```

the code above works, but the following doesn't work

```
ghost method lemma2(A:array<int>)
    requires A.Length>2
    requires forall i:: 0 <= i-1 < i < A.Length ==> A[i-1] <= A[i]
    ensures A[0] <= A[2]
{
}

ghost method lemma3(A:array<int>)
    requires A.Length>2
    requires forall i:: 0 <= i-1 < i < A.Length ==> A[i-1] <= A[i]
    ensures forall i,j :: 0 <= i < j < A.Length ==> A[i] <= A[j]
{
}
```

Problem: A postcondition might not hold on this return path.

What extra preconditions does it require?

Answer (score 2):

No extra preconditions are required here. Dafny (more correctly underlying Z3) uses heuristics to prove. It looks like dafny need some help here to figure out proofs as heuristics are not able to figure out by itself. You can ask dafny to `assert` things which makes it first prove it and then add it as part of knowledge base for applying further heuristics to prove latter goals.

```
ghost method lemma2(A:array<int>)
    requires A.Length>2
    requires forall i:: 0 <= i-1 < i < A.Length ==> A[i-1] <= A[i]
    ensures A[0] <= A[2]
{
    assert A[0] <= A[1];
    assert A[1] <= A[2];
}
```

For second code snippet, a `while` loop with single assert inside it is enough to guide dafny towards proof. Earlier loop iteration has  proved that `forall m, n :: 0 <= m < n < i ==> A[m] <= A[n]`. Current loop iteration need to prove `forall m, n :: 0 <= m < n < i + 1 ==> A[m] <= A[n]` for which `assert A[i-1] <= A[i]` hint is enough for dafny.

```
ghost method lemma3(A:array<int>)
    requires A.Length>2
    requires forall i:: 0 <= i-1 < i < A.Length ==> A[i-1] <= A[i]
    ensures forall i,j :: 0 <= i < j < A.Length ==> A[i] <= A[j]
{
     var i := 0;
     
     while i < A.Length
      invariant i <= A.Length
      invariant forall m, n :: 0 <= m < n < i ==> A[m] <= A[n]
     {
        if i >= 1 {
            assert A[i-1] <= A[i];
        }
        i := i + 1;
     }
}
```